# How to pass data from one component ajax response to another component state reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component.

**Emp.js**

```
class Emp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employee: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        phone_number: '',
        hire_date: '',
        salary: '',
        email: '',
        manager: null,
        department: {
          department_id: 102
        }
      }
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

**Table.js**

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.editClick = this.editClick.bind(this);
  }}
```

in table.js there is edit button which call this handler.

This editClick get value from ajax and populate form for editing.

```
editClick() {
    let employee_id = event.target.value;
    console.log('edit emp:', employee_id);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'getEmp/' + employee_id,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { employee_id: employee_id },
      async: true,
      success: function (result) {
        //populate empForm 
        var form = $("#empForm");
        var i;
        for (i in result) {
          form.find('[name="' + i + '"]').val(result[i]);
        }

      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
```

How to set this result value from Table class edit to state of Emp class?

set result of ajax from Table component to Emp component state?

Comment: How `Emp` component is placed/rendered in reference to `Table` component ?

Comment: @Mohammad Sahil why are you adding values to form? if you want to pass data to other component through state

Comment: If `Emp` is a direct child of `Table` you can pass the data as a prop: `<Emp data={this.state.data} />`, then in `Emp` use `this.props.data`. If they are siblings or don't have a direct relation in the rendering tree, you'll have to use redux or the contex API in order to share the data. Also keep in mind that is preferable to use arrow functions in the ajax callback in order to have access to `this.setState()` in that context.

Comment: @HS <div><div id="root"></div><div id="root2"></div></div>

Comment: @VahidAkhtar these are two different component on same page. value added to form but its not in state object this is making issue.

Comment: @MohammadSahil - if they are sibling, then use a common parent where the state lives and share the state by passing it down both the children.